# time complexity of two nested loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm studying algorithms and I've met a problem, that I can't solve.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for( int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        sum++;
```

So, time complexity of this code is n^2. But. First loop is iterating n times and I understand that. But second one is iterating n(n+1)/2. So.. It becomes n*(n(n+1))/2. Where I went wrong?

Comment: The second one is _not_ iterating `n(n+1)/2`.  If `i` is 100, it's not going to increment `sum` 4950 times.

Answer (score 3):

First thing you need to understand Big-O notation. It throws all lower order terms and keeps only the highest `N`.

Your outer loop runs `N` times ,so the highest term is `n` and what is the highest `value` for inner loop? It's `(n-1)`.

So for `Nth` iteration of outer loop, you get `n-1` iteration for inner loop which is `N(N-1)  = (N^2 - N)` and with big-O it's `O(N^2)`

Comment: Thank you, I realized my mistake right away